# How should I organize preprocessors and their outputs in a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, preprocessor, github-pages

In my GitHub Pages repository, I work with preprocessors such as Pandoc (for `.md` to `.html`) and LESS (for `.less` to `.css`). I need their outputs to represent the website of them for the Pages webpage but I also need the original files.

At the moment, the repository holds all four files, but feel as it's redundant since two pairs of files represent essentially the same thing.

A similar situation exists for CoffeeScript.

Is my current approach the way to go, or is there a better way?

Comment: Is this problem really different from choosing to include or not compiled binaries or bytecode in your repository? Is there anything configuration-specific in your output files (i.e. they could be different for someone else)? If so, it advocates *against* inclusion. Does your documentation about your compilation chain / dev environment clearly identifies the tools you are using and their configuration, so that any user could painlessly generate the exact same files? If so it can be another argument if you choose non-inclusion.